# Language finite automata difference

Tags: finite-automata

what's the difference between

```
L1 = {m ∈ (a + b)*} L1 = {m ∈ (a , b)*}
```

i feel like there is no difference but i cant really understand the difference between this `+` and the plus in this expression for example `(a,b)+`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no difference. `a+b` translates to `a union b` and `(a , b)` is another (albeit much less common) way that some researchers refer to `a union b`. If you so choose to continue your study of automata you will find that there is an incredible variety of ways that different researchers refer to the same concepts. In this instance alone, off the top of my head I know this can be written as:

`L1 = {m ∈ (a + b)*}`
`L1 = {m ∈ (a , b)*}`
`L1 = {m ∈ (a | b)*}`
`L1 = {m ∈ (a U b)*}`